# How to include white space and n\ in this code

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, caesar-cipher

I'm making a caesar cipher program. I import a txt file, but all comes out as one big sentence. How do I get the spaces and new lines in there?

```
with open("output.txt", "r") as results:
    data = results.read().replace("\n", "").lower()

alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
key = 0
cipher = ""

for c in data:
    if c in alphabet:
        cipher += alphabet[(alphabet.index(c) + key) % (len(alphabet))]

print("Your encrypted message is:" + cipher)

Your encrypted message is:firstcustomerwhatwillyoubeusingtheaccountforpersonaluseexistingcustomernotitlemrlastnamealrfirstnamenamenameingson
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

You are explicitly deleting the newlines from the read data by using the following line in your code,

```
data = results.read().replace('\n','').lower()
```

Also, in order to include the spaces and newlines in your code, you will have to add the newline and space characters unmodified to the code.

### Solution

If you want to preserve the spaces and newlines simply modify your lines as follows:

```
with open("output.txt", "r") as results:
    data = results.read().lower()

alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
key = 0
cipher = ""

for c in data:
    if c in alphabet:
        cipher += alphabet[(alphabet.index(c) + key) % (len(alphabet))]
    elif c in [' ', '\n']:
        cipher += c
print("Your encrypted message is:" + cipher)
```

Comment: Really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Issue:

When you use `replace("\n", "")` in your loop, **it replaces the newline (\n) with a no-space character.**

```
with open("output.txt", "r") as results:
    data = results.read().replace("\n", "").lower()
```

If you don't wish to remove newline, you need to skip the `replace` part.

## Corrected:

```
with open("output.txt", "r") as results:
        data = results.read().lower()
```

There's nothing in your code that replaces any blanks, you can try to add a few spaces and test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Do not replace "\n" with """", It will work fine then.